# How do I Access PDOException after the Catch

Tags: php, pdo

In the following code, "$e" gets "getMessage()". I know i can use the "catch {}" to either print it to the screen or store the contents in a variable for later use, but what if I didnt want to do that? How can I access it later? I saw there is " getPrevious()", but how do I access that from another function later on, or can I?:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I Have tried things like the following to see if I could access the info, but I cant get the syntax correct?:

```
function ShowLater(){
    // Cant figure out how to access the info :(
    echo PDO::PDOExeption,$e->getMessage();
    echo PDO::PDOExeption,$e->getPrevious();
}

ShowLater();
```

Basically, How do I access what would be shown in

```
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
```

Later on outside of the "catch {}"

What variable would I echo?

Answer (score 0):

connection can be found in your $conn variable,  PHP stops code execution when there is an error in the try{} block then jump to catch{} block, that means you can be able to report what happened in the catch block by printing the error description in the $e->getMessage()

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an error stack accessible after the fact for Exceptions caught or not caught in php.  If you do not catch the Exception it will stop the execution of the script.  However it looks like you can pass in a previous Exception once caught as an argument for an Exception and then later, loop through all previous exceptions to get them after the fact.  However after saying all that, why not just store them in a variable and report on them later.  Look at the example given for `getPrevious()` [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/exception.getprevious.php#example-306) for help on how to implement it.